# Cookies in web application are deleted

Tags: c#, .net, web, cookies

I have a web aplication where I'm working with cookies. The problem is that
in a form "A", I save the cookies with the following code in Javascript.

```
function uploadCookieMesa(dataCookie) {

    saveCookie('qr_rest_c_icod', dataCookie.rest_c_icod); 
    saveCookie('qr_rest_c_vnomb', dataCookie.rest_c_vnomb); 
    saveCookie('qr_loca_c_icod', dataCookie.loca_c_icod); 
    saveCookie('qr_loca_c_vnomb', dataCookie.loca_c_vnomb); 
    saveCookie('qr_mesa_c_icod', dataCookie.mesa_c_icod); 
    saveCookie('qr_mesa_cli_c_icod', dataCookie.mesa_cli_c_icod); 
    saveCookie('qr_clie_c_icod', dataCookie.clie_c_icod); 
    saveCookie('qr_mesa_cli_c_vcomentario', dataCookie.mesa_cli_c_vcomentario); 
}

function saveCookie(name,value) {

    var expiresdate = new Date(2068, 1, 02, 11, 20);
    document.cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "; expires=" + expiresdate.toUTCString();

}
```

Cookie in chrome:

---

[image: Cookie in chrome]

In this form, I could save the values but when I enter another form "B". 
This cookies are cleaning.

I need you help.  Thanks!!!

Comment: What is `dataCookie` equal to every time you submit the form? Is B maybe not passing `dataCookie` in?

Comment: It is an object, if you save the information in each variable cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your cookies will only be sent for requests to the page where they were set (form A).

Add a path parameter of `;path=/` to the end of them - this will tell the browser to send them on requests to all pages on your site, including form B.